# How to automatically generate the Login ID for an new user in java?

Tags: java, random, generator

In an registration page (eg. yahoo etc) the login ID is automatically generated using the information given by the user. I want to implement the same thing. Can any one give the code to generate the loginID by giving inputs such as FirstName LastName DOB MiddleName etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "login ID"? If you think of a session ID, your web framework should take care of it. Another way of creating possibly not unique (!) sort of random string is using checksums like MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: loginID means (xxxxx@yahoo.com,xxxx@yahoo.in,xxx@yahoo.co.in) this is automatically generated (or suggested) by yahoo site when u are newly registering. So what code do the use in order to shuffle the users details?

Answer (score 2):

You could generate an `ID` by concatenating all your strings (`FirstName`, etc.) and use `String#hashcode()`.

If you want it to be **random** you can add random characters before or a random number after using hashcode.

Comment: well I am pity new to this coding can u post any example. Please!!

Comment: int loginID = (firstName+middleName+lastName+DOB).hashCode();

Answer (score 1):

You should have multiple ways to suggest a login id:

1. Suffix DOB to name.
2. Suffix `0123` to name.
3. Prefix version of above two point.
4. and similarly many other ways you can try.

Check if the automatically generated login id already exists in DB and show to user only non-existing ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(lengthOfRandomString)
```

or

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(lengthOfRandomString)
```

or

```
RandomStringUtils.random(lengthOfRandomString)
```